# How to write lambda expression in pandas that uses multiple columns and column names?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I want to achieve the following using pandas lambda expressions

1. find the value in the column whose name is in the column 'ideal_prime_fc'
2. find the value in the column whose name is in the column 'prime_fc'
3. find difference and put in a new column 'delta'

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMxjn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like the following work for you?

Write a function to subtract the values in the two prime values columns:

```
def get_col_name(x):
    try:
        ip_fc = x['ideal_prime_fc']
        p_fc = x['prime_fc']
        return x[ip_fc]-x[p_fc]
    except IndexError:
        return float('NaN')  # handle non-existent values however you'd prefer
```

Apply the function, assigning to a new column:

```
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_col_name(x), axis=1)
```

A truncated example output:

```
983     976     ideal_prime_fc  prime_fc    diff
2835    780     973             805         NaN
8       2259    983             983         0.0
2851    796     973             805         NaN
13      7       983             976         6.0   # added for test
```

Comment: No. For example, in the row 0, ideal_prime_fc = 973 and prime_fc = 805. I want to search 805 and 973 in column names and find the difference df.iloc[0]['973'] - df.iloc[0]['805']

Comment: @Vinay I've updated my answer based on your clarification

Comment: Glad to hear, please accept answer if you have a chance.